# Rewrite/permalink errors when setting pages as parents for custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I've been trying to accomplish the following:

1. create a custom post type *"vehicles"* and a single-vehicles.php for it (done, no problems)
2. create a *page* "fleets" and a *page* "fleet europe" (done, no problems)
3. set "fleets" as a parent page for "fleet europe" (done, no problems)
4. create a *vehicle* custom post called "red family van" (done, no problems)
5. make the *vehicle* custom post type hierarchical, and allow it to have pages as parents (done, no problem)
6. set the "fleet europe" *page* as parent for the "red family van" *vehicle* and go to the settings-permalinks page and update the permalinks(done, but the permalink structure breaks)

**Symptoms**

The resulting permalink structure looks okay (mypage.com/fleets/fleets/fleet-europe/red-family-van), but when accessing any *vehicle* post, wordpress cannot rewrite properly, the network tab shows a 404 and wordpress defaults back to an empty page with only header and footer and no content (because there's no 404 page specified).

**What I've attempted**

First, I've tried to unparent the "red family van" *vehicle* from the "fleet europe" *page*. Then everything works again. Parenting the *vehicle* with any *page* breaks the permalinks again.

Secondly, I've tried to experiment with the

```
'hierarchical' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fleets', 'with_front' => true, 'pages' => true),
```

parameters in my post-vehicles.php (pasted below). No matter whether 'pages' is true or false, no matter the slug, no matter the 'with_front, parenting a *page* to a *vehicle* always breaks things.

Then I've tried to analyze and modify the permalink structure with an assortment of plugins, none of which helped me identify the problem - according to them "everything should work fine :)"

Finally, I've read through any stackoverflow post that seemed to deal with a similar issue, but people seem to be only pointing to setting the post-type rewrite parameters I already have in place as suggested.

**What my code looks like**

Functions.php - allowing parenting pages for *vehicles* in the backend through a metabox:

```
//removing the standard hierarchy parenting metabox, because that only allows parenting vehicles with vehicles
add_action('admin_menu', function() { 
   remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'vehicles', 'normal');
});

//adding a custom metabox that allows the parenting of pages to vehicles
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() { 
   add_meta_box('vehicle-parent', 'Parent Page', 'vehicle_attributes_meta_box', 'vehicles', 'side', 'high');
});

// building the dropdown for the pages to be selectable in the metabox
function vehicle_attributes_meta_box($post) { 
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);


    if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
            $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array(
                    'post_type'         => 'page', 
                    'selected'      => $post->post_parent, 
                    'name'          => 'parent_id', 
                    'show_option_none'  => __('(no parent)'), 
                    'sort_column'       => 'menu_order, post_title', 
                    'echo'          => 0
        ));


            if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
                echo $pages;
            } 
        }
}
```

post-vehicles.php - setting up the custom post type *vehicles*:

```
function fleet_management_post_type_vehicles() {


    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'taxonomies' => array('vehicles_category'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fleets', 'with_front' => true, 'pages' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-post',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes'),
    );

    register_post_type('vehicles', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'fleet_management_post_type_vehicles');
```

Any and all pointers are appreciated!